# Can I write Strings into a .JSON-File without using JSON Library

Tags: java, json

I need to write formatted Strings into a .json File without using the JSON library.
If I try to use the following code to write a test string I don't get a result inside the .json-File.

```java
FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Test.json");` 
file.write("test");
```

Comment: Firstly, that's not valid JSON. Secondly, you're not closing the writer (in the code you've shown) which may be the problem. I'd suggest using either `Files.write` or `Files.newBufferedWriter` with a try-with-resources block.

Comment: What do you mean by not valid JSON?
Sorry for asking studip questions, I've never worked with JSON before

Comment: `test` is not valid JSON. You should still be able to write it to the file, but it won't be a valid JSON file. Fundamentally your question isn't really about JSON though - it's just about writing to a text file.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. Yes, you're right, it's not valid JSON. It is an exercise to learn how to handle work with NIO.
If I close the file after writing the String it worked!

Comment: Why? Why not use the correct tool for the job? No point in re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Because I'm about to learn JavaSE. I know it's kind of re-inventing the wheel, buts it's my task not to use external librarys

Answer (score 1):

1. Json looks something like that:

> ```
> {
>     "glossary": {
>         "title": "example glossary",
>       "GlossDiv": {
>             "title": "S",
>           "GlossList": {
>                 "GlossEntry": {
>                     "ID": "SGML",
>                   "SortAs": "SGML",
>                   "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
>                   "Acronym": "SGML",
>                   "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
>                   "GlossDef": {
>                         "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
>                       "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
>                     },
>                   "GlossSee": "markup"
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

You have key-value pairs there. Then you use Brackets to define the structure.

2. You need to use something like file.flush() when you want to write.

**Explanation**: When you are writing to a file, Java does not want to send each letter to it individually. Therefore it stores them until an certain point is reached if you dont reach that point it wont send the data to the file.
To force it, to send the Data use the flush()-Method.